# Error after migration omnifaces 3.7.1 to 3.8.1 validateBean with UIComponent

Tags: jsf, bean-validation, omnifaces

I'm recently migrate my jsf webapp to omnifaces 3.8.1 and i'm getting an error on validateBean.

This seams to be caused by UIComponent property in bean.

```
11:10:18,385 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-9) UT005023: Exception handling request to /myexample-hr/faces/create.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
        at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
        at io.opentracing.contrib.opentracing-jaxrs2//io.opentracing.contrib.jaxrs2.server.SpanFinishingFilter.doFilter(SpanFinishingFilter.java:52)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//com.umanxpert.myexample.hrweb.filter.TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(TwoFactorAuthenticationFilter.java:35)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//com.umanxpert.myexample.hrweb.filter.JSecurityCheckFilter.doFilter(JSecurityCheckFilter.java:29)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//com.umanxpert.myexample.hrweb.base.MultiTenancyFilter.doFilter(MultiTenancyFilter.java:32)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@21.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
        at io.undertow.core@2.2.2.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.2.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.getBeanProperty(Reflection.java:377)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromList(Reflection.java:486)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:471)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromMap(Reflection.java:496)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:474)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPath(Reflection.java:517)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPathsFromBean(Reflection.java:509)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.collectBasePropertyPaths(Reflection.java:480)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.getBaseBeanPropertyPaths(Reflection.java:462)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateBean.validateCopiedBean(ValidateBean.java:404)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateBean.processValidateBean(ValidateBean.java:378)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.taghandler.ValidateBean.lambda$apply$0(ValidateBean.java:339)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Events.lambda$wrap$1(Events.java:332)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Events$4.afterPhase(Events.java:368)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.eventlistener.CallbackPhaseListener.afterPhase(CallbackPhaseListener.java:68)
        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:164)
        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:82)
        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:110)
        at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:177)
        at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:707)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at deployment.myexample-application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.ear.myexample-hr-web.war//org.omnifaces.util.Reflection.getBeanProperty(Reflection.java:374)
        ... 107 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempting to use a Behavior feature with a component that does not support any event types. Component must implement BehaviourHolder interface.
        at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.assertClientBehaviorHolder(UIComponentBase.java:1727)
        at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.getDefaultEventName(UIComponentBase.java:1712)
        ... 112 more
```

Should UIComponent be excluded from the property types needed for recursion?

Is there any workaround to keep my UIComponent property and validateBean?

Comment: You are right, i edit my post with full stack. Let me now if you need an example. thank you

Comment: Ah, I now see what you mean. So your validable bean has an `UIComponent` property? This is in first place strange as this doesn't represent a real world model property .. Perhaps your bean is a bit too much tight-coupled? E.g. "view" and "model" properties mixed in same class?

Comment: @BalusC once again you're right. I'm using validation on a "view" bean and yes, i had a UIComponent property on my bean. Maybe i need to re-think this and have a more clear separation between "view" and "model". I removed the property and now everything is working. Thank you for your help.